# pandas problem making regex for str.contains "|" 'apple[red]', 'apple[green]'

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

Let's assume my dataframe

```
    Name    Value
0   K       apple
1   Y       banana
2   B       orange
3   Q       grape
4   C       apple
5   A       apple
```

and my code`s

```
mylist = ['apple']
df1 = df['Value'].str.contains("|".join(mylist))

df['Label'] = df1
df = df[df['Label'].astype('str').str.startswith('True')]
```

**output**

```
    Name    Value
0   K       apple
4   C       apple
5   A       apple
```

**My Question**

when my dataframe like below,

```
    Name    Value
0   K       apple[red]
1   Y       banana[yellow]
2   B       orange[orange]
3   Q       grape[purple]
4   C       apple[red]
5   A       apple[green]
```

and my code is

```
mylist = ['apple[red]', 'apple[green]']
df1 = df['Value'].str.contains("|".join(mylist))

df['Label'] = df1
df = df[df['Label'].astype('str').str.startswith('True')]
```

When I run the code and see the result,
It doesn't recognize anything. The result is an empty value.

**output what I want**

```
    Name    Value
0   K       apple[red]
4   C       apple[red]
5   A       apple[green]
```

thank you for reading.

Comment: why not `df[df.Value.isin(mylist)]`?

Comment: I edited the title; this was an issue with [tag:pandas] not base [tag:python]. And you needed to form a regex matching multiple patterns, so tagged [tag:regex]. Your regex contains '[' and ']' which are special characters and need to be escaped.

Comment: You don't have any regular expressions in your list and you can use the method `isin` as @luigigi pointed.

Comment: @luigigi @Mykola Zotko thank you, I`ll refer it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because possible some special `regex` values, use `re.escape`:

```
import re

mylist = ['apple[red]', 'apple[green]']

df1 = df[df['Value'].str.contains("|".join(re.escape(x) for x in mylist))]
print (df1)
  Name         Value
0    K    apple[red]
4    C    apple[red]
5    A  apple[green]
```

Comment: It's been a while @jezrael. I get a message that I can adopt an answer after 7minutes. I'll do it later. Thanks anyway!